# What's the metaphorical meaning of "off-ramp"?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

Example:

> Blinken said the US had sought to provide off-ramps to the Russian leader, but “every time there's been an opportunity to” take them, “he's pressed the accelerator and continued down this horrific road that he's been pursuing.”

Recently I've been reading about Ukraine, and I see this word ALL THE TIME. I know the rough meaning but want a more clear understanding, and I find it strange the metaphorical meaning isn't in dictionaries.

Comment: "Off Ramp" is a slightly less formal way to say "[Exit Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_strategy)"

Comment: thanks J. and nice link

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**An off-ramp is a way out of a situation**, as used by US politicians.
A real off-ramp is in the picture on the right side. Here, it means to give Putin a way to get out of the situation he's put Ukraine in.

Here is what it is:

[off-ramp from Tucson.com] [image: ][1]]

> CAPTION: As a part of the larger interchange project, the southbound
> Interstate 19 off ramp at Ajo Way will be closed early Friday morning.
>
> Mike Christy / Arizona Daily Star

Comment: Thanks Lam.  I agree.

Comment: double-took when I saw that image. drive that near every day

Answer (score 6):

Off-ramps are connecting roads from an interstate road to a typically smaller road. Usually you used an off-ramp to get off the interstate. It means metaphorically that the US gave Russia a chance to change their mind about the path they were taking. They could take an off-ramp (provided by the US) from their current plan to some other plan.

Here is an example:
If I was going to school but could not afford it and had to take out much debt to do it. I may want to just stop going to school and get a job. And, let's say I had a bad resume like quitting jobs early and poor references. Then I may feel forced to keep with my plan of going into debt for school. And, let's say my friend is a successful business man. He could "provide me an off-ramp" by offering a job to me that paid well despite my resume.

So Russia in the same way could see their plan as the only way, and the US could provide an alternative plan (off-ramp) that allows them (Russia) to divert from their original plan.

Comment: British speakers might call the both the figurative and the literal thing an 'exit'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Same for AmE, worth noting.

Comment: Roughly speaking, in US English, the exit is the junction considered abstractly, and the off-ramp is the strip of pavement that you drive on as you are taking the exit. Sometimes people want to be clear that they are using a metaphor, and "exit" is such a general term that talk of providing an exit for Putin, while perfectly fine, lacks color.

Comment: And British speakers would say _university_ in Eli's example - our schools are for the under-18s.

Comment: Isn't a ramp inclined? What about non-elevated freeways where the ground is flat?

Comment: @Michael_Harvey it's always elevated in the metaphor? BTW in UK English it's an "exit slip" [road], elevated or not.

Comment: @nigel222 - I agree that 'exit slip' is _one_ way of referring to motorway/freeway exit roads, or slip roads. The Highway Code, section 273: "Unless signs indicate that a lane leads directly off the motorway, you will normally leave the motorway by a slip road on your left."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey off-ramp is used for [any road](https://www.bing.com/search?q=off-ramp+define&cvid=108822119ea144c197031e9bdebf1f81&aqs=edge.0.0l3j69i64.3077j0j1&pglt=43&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=DCTS), elevated or not, that connects other roads, but yes usually it's an actual ramp. In most cases, such as the metaphor, "ramp" is referring to the **gradual transition from road to road** not the gradual transition in height.

Comment: @KateBunting fair point, as I am sure you know, we call higher education "college" but have both colleges and universities. I used "school" here, as it is often used in the US, to mean any type of learning. This could be a college, university, certificate program, private high school, trade school, or any other learning opportunity. If I meant to only reference higher education I would have said "college." Thank you for pointing out and clarifying for readers!

Comment: Thanks Eli and all.

Comment: @kal sure thing!

Comment: @EliHarold - My point was that you don't have to finance your own education at school (in the British sense).

Comment: @KateBunting even private highshcool (secondary school) or the other forms that I mentioned such as trade school and certifications such as a python coding certification? Or would you not consider those school?

Comment: @EliHarold - I'm talking about mainstream primary/secondary education. Of course private education is financed by the parents, not the child. But all this is irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @KateBunting lol true, definitely irrelevant, I am just always curious to learn British culture. It's crazy how much difference there is so it's interesting to me.

Comment: @EliHarold In that case, note that "_and the off-ramp is the strip of **pavement** that you drive on_" sounds strange in the UK. A "_pavement_" is the thing at the side of roads-much-smaller-than-a-freeway where pedestrians walk. We would probably say strip of tarmac/road/carriage-way.

Comment: @TripeHound interesting, we call asphalt "pavement" and the "the thing at the side of roads-much-smaller-than-a-freeway where pedestrians walk," "Sidewalks" and/or "concrete."

Answer (score 3):

This started as a comment in response to @MichaelHarvey 's comment "British speakers might call the both the figurative and the literal thing an 'exit'." posted in response to Eli Harold's answer, but I think it merits an answer of its own:

The exit is the part of the highway that goes to the offramp. The off-ramp is the part from where you're completely off the highway to where you're on a normal street. Metaphorically, an "exit" would just be a course of action through which he is no longer invading Ukraine, and there's no need for the world to give him that; he can do it on his own. Literally, an off-ramp is a stretch of road that takes drivers not merely *off* the highway, but *on* to regular street. Looking at Lambie's picture, the right car on the right is right around the part where the exit turns into the off-ramp. I would say by the time you get to the things with orange and white diagonal stripes, you're off the freeway. But just having that wouldn't be very useful, would it? If you just had that, and nothing past it, that would take you off the freeway, but you'd be stranded with no way to get anywhere.

Metaphorically, the idea of an off-ramp is not merely to get out of the immediate situation, but to get into a situation that's acceptable. Just getting Putin to stop the invasion is not realistic; we need to find a way of him leaving Ukraine *and* saving face, and not feeling like he's put himself in an untenable situation.

Comment: Side note: An 'off-ramp' is called a 'slip road' in BrE - https://www.thefreedictionary.com/slip+road

Comment: Thanks Accc. Very nuanced and you have a point. I like the point that the new situation is acceptable, though I think "exit" can imply that too.

Comment: @RobinElvin Google navigation even in the UK used to say "take the ramp" to mean take the sliproad.  When the sliproad was flat and the alternative was to go up a slope onto a flyover (overpass), the meaning was inverted.  I got very lost.

Comment: @RobinElvin imo (late 20s British driver) "slip road" refers primarily to the flat piece of tarmac used to join a motorway immediately after an on-ramp, and secondarily to the flat piece of tarmac to exit a motorway immediately before an off-ramp. The ramp itself would be a tertiary meaning

Comment: @ChrisH Google navigation in the UK as far as I have experienced uses American vocabulary with a British (English) voice.

Comment: @RobinElvin it's got a little better, but when it switched from an American to a British voice without changing the vocabulary was the peak of confusion for me because the cue to translate wasn't there.  As for its handling of Welsh place names....

Comment: @Tristan As a 50yo British driver to me the term "slip-road" always includes any ramp. I had never heard the terms on- or off-ramp until recently. See this post and comment no. 1 by David Richerby - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/127394/uk-motorway-slip-roads-speed-limit

Comment: I'm a few years younger than Robin (and I believe David R is a bit younger than me).  While I've heard "on-/off- ramp" enough that they're familiar, they seem like complete Americanisms and I only recall hearing them in American accents or US contexts (I've used the term myself when visiting LA)

Comment: @RobinElvin I never said it didn't include the ramp. Just that it isn't what I primarily think of when I hear the term (which is the lane used to join or leave the main road). I don't know if this is idiosyncratic on my part or if it's a shift in meaning, which is why I included my age

Answer (score 3):

To give some context, America has long had controlled-access highways in and around cities. During a family vacation, driving through an unfamiliar city in the days before cell-phone directions, it was common to be trapped on an interstate highway. Maybe you missed the correct exit, or you saw the kids' favorite restaurant off to the side. Now you're stuck going the wrong way, very fast, sometimes for miles, with no way to turn around, desperately looking for an off-ramp. It was a common American experience.

"Looking for an off-ramp" is a metaphor for that feeling of being trapped going the wrong way.

It's not all that common. "A way out of the situation" or just "a way out" is better in most cases. But the rest of the sentence "*he's pressed the accelerator and continued down this horrific road*" is so good that the expression works here.

Comment: Thanks. Very good. Didn't think of that.